# Typescript and Atom on Mac: What is recommended build tool?

Tags: typescript

What's the right build tool (gulp, grunt, other) to use for a nice development workflow using Atom, Typescript and Atom-Typescript?

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio Code? It's an enhanced Atom, and supports TypeScript by default :) https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: VS code doesn't provide build support by default. You need gulp / grunt / something else. It does provide nice integration points for these *external tools that use needs to setup* though.

Comment: Yes I have tried VSC (as well as sublimetext3+Typescript, and WebStorm, Eclipse+TypeECS and one more who's name escapes me. So far Atom came closest to "just working". Web storm (like other Jetbrains IDEs) for some reason I find always confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the right build tool

Atom-Typescript can compile your js files on the fly and keep them in sync so you don't need anything on the dev machine.

That said it uses `ntypescript` which has build server support baked in : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript#grunt

Comment: But I thought you do... As we've discussed on other threads, if my app has multiple files I need someway to properly prepare the .js files so that I can run them (on node). Maybe what's needed is a pointer to a "hello world" example in typescript with 2 classes, three files, 30 lines of code, that go from edit to execution.